# selecting unique combination of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table:

```
create table cric_country
(
id int,
country varchar (20)
)
insert into cric_country values
(1,'Ind'),(2,'Aus'),(3,'NZ')
```

I need to get the playing fixture for the countries where I need 2 columns for country and should omit same country and repeated matches:
I wrote the below query :

```
select
t1.country,t2.country
from cric_country t1
inner join
cric_country t2
on t1.country <> t2.country
```

But Its not solving the purpose as I have Aus/Ind as well Ind/Aus, need to omit one but cannot do a distinct.

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: Aus/Ind, NZ/Ind, NZ/Aus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.country country1, b.country country2
FROM   cric_country a
       CROSS JOIN cric_country b
WHERE  a.country < b.country
ORDER  BY a.country, b.country
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21bb0/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ COUNTRY1 ║ COUNTRY2 ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║ Aus      ║ Ind      ║
║ Aus      ║ NZ       ║
║ Ind      ║ NZ       ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: could use `inner join ... on a.country < b.country` also

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
SELECT t1.country c1, t2.country c2
  FROM cric_country t1 JOIN cric_country t2 ON t1.id > t2.id;
```